# NDB Query Chaining oddity - Order + Inequality?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I just spent a few hours debugging something that seems odd. However, I can't tell if it is a bug or I'm just doing something wrong. Short version, it seems if I have an inequality filter on an NDB query AND an order, they must be the same line.

Note: All the data shown below was created in order, even though I was futzing with the dates in the datastore so some do not have microseconds.

```
#Q1. Yields the correct results:
q = BlogPost.query().filter(BlogPost.published_date > PUBLISHED_DATE_MIN).order(-BlogPost.published_date)
for p in q.fetch(1000):
   print "%s - %s" %  (p.published_date, p.title)

# 2014-03-02 21:49:25 - First
# 2014-03-01 22:51:14.998963 - Should be 2nd
# 2014-03-01 21:49:54.273152 - Should be Third
```

Here is what I initially had. Note: order is on separate line

```
q = BlogPost.query().filter(BlogPost.published_date > PUBLISHED_DATE_MIN)
q.order(-BlogPost.published_date)

for p in q.fetch(1000):
    print "%s - %s" %  (p.published_date, p.title)
# 2014-03-01 21:49:54.273152 - Should be Third
# 2014-03-01 22:51:14.998963 - Should be 2nd
# 2014-03-02 21:49:25 - First
```

The NDB query appears to just be unordered or reverse ordered, however, then I remove the inequality and I get:

```
q = BlogPost.query() #.filter(BlogPost.published_date > PUBLISHED_DATE_MIN)
q.order(-BlogPost.published_date)

for p in q.fetch(1000):
    print "%s - %s" %  (p.published_date, p.title)
 # 2014-03-02 21:49:25 - First
 # 2014-03-01 22:51:14.998963 - Should be 2nd
 # 2014-03-01 21:49:54.273152 - Should be Third
```

I am seeing this behavior in the sdk console as well as the remote console and on the actual appspot when I deploy my code. Is this a bug (not likely) or something I am missing?

Comment: You are confusing the behavior of `db` with `ndb`  see @Greg answer below. You might also want to look at the ndb cheat sheet - the Queries section https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

Answer (score 4):

When you run `q.order(-BlogPost.published_date)` it creates and returns a new query which you aren't assigning to anything.
You want to have:

```
q = q.order(-BlogPost.published_date)
```